# how to trigger UI update when alertdialog gets dismissed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog which appears initiated by a BroadcastReceiver - so the AlertDialog may appear ontop of ANY of my activities without knowing which activityis actually under it.

```
private void showAlert(Context context, String s) {
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .create();
alertDialog.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.SMS_Alert_title));
alertDialog.setMessage(s);
alertDialog.setButton(context.getString(R.string.alert_OK),
    new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        return; //can't call the underlying activity's ui update method bec I don't know which activity is actually underlying
        }
    });
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
alertDialog.show();
}
```

When I now press the "OK" button on the AlertDialog to dismiss it, the pressed status of all my buttons in the underlying activity become unpressed. I need them to remain pressed simply because my buttons show a different png during pressed status - which I also use to show that they are and remain "ON" when pressed. (I can't use toggle buttons in this case)

Ideally I just need to update my UI of the underlying activity but `onResume` is NOT called when the AlertDialog gets dismissed.

Also I cannot call any UI update method when pressing the ALertDialog OK button, since I do not know which activity is actually under the AlertDialog (as the ALertDialog may appear ontop of any activity)

(I hope I could explain the problem well enough)

ps While I could change the background of the unpressed buttons to the pressed png instead of just saying `btn.setPressed(true)` I would like to avoid it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. But have a go at following.

Have an interface named... say 'PressableActivity'? which has one method. 'pressAllButtons'

Implement this on all your activities you want the explained functionality, and implement the method to press all buttons when called.

Have a variable of type 'PressableActivity' on your context (or even a static class and a static variable will do.)

Assign this variable to the activity being displayed when it gets a call to onResume.

When you create the dialog, set an onDismissListener to it, which calls the 'pressAllButtons' method on the object pointed by static variable on your context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks - I understand, this is a good approach to "remember" which activity should catch the onDismissListener. Either I go this route or implement my dialog as an activity which would enforce the onResume of the underlying activity as soon as it disappears

Answer (score 1):

One way or another you're going to need to "know" which activity is being displayed after the AlertDialog is dismissed. You can set an onDismissListener on your AlertDialog inside of your Activity and then respond accordingly. Why you would want your buttons to remain in a pressed state after they are not pressed is beyond me, but if that's what you really want then just set the state to pressed since that's essentially what you want: a forced pressed state even though the user hasn't pressed it again.

Comment: the dialog is being created by the BroadCast listener - so I can't set the onDismissListener within the activity which would implement it. It seems that either I have to "remember" the active activity like Madushan suggested or I have to recode the dialog in an Activity which looks like a dialog...

Comment: I know it sounds weird - just a little background about the buttons. some buttons are used to turn on/off some device via wifi, BT or SMS. So the button should remain in the "ON" state. But I cant't use toglle buttons since it may always be that the device does not receive the command the user might have to press again - so he can press the same "ON" button again even though it shows in it's pressed png. WIth toggle buttons one cannot press "ON" again but one would have to press "off" - hope this explains a little more - thanks very much!